# PWA html básica no aparece instalador pero el serviceworker se registra con éxito

Tags: html, pwa, console

Dentro de *public_html* hice una carpeta llamada PWATEST, dentro de esta misma meti **`pwaprueba.html`**, **`serviceWorker.js`** y **`manifest.json`**.

Intente de mil formas, pero no logro que andar el instalador de mi web PWA.

En la consola registra el *serviceWorker* con éxito pero sale abajo :

> serviceWorker.js:10 Error al almacenar en caché: TypeError: Failed to execute 'addAll' on 'Cache': Request failed

[image: En la pestaña Aplicación sale lo siguiente]

```js
// serviceWorker.js
self.addEventListener('install', event => {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open('my-cache').then(cache => {
      return cache.addAll([
          './',
          'pwaprueba.html',
        ])
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('Error al almacenar en caché:', error);
        });
    })
  );
});


self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request).then(response => {
      return response || fetch(event.request);
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('Evento beforeinstallprompt activado en el Service Worker.');
  deferredPrompt = event;
  console.log('Evento beforeinstallprompt activado.');
  // Muestra el botón de instalación o realiza alguna acción para indicar al usuario que la PWA está lista para ser instalada.
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://i.imgur.com/QRAUqs9.png" />
  <title>PWA Prueba</title>
</head>

<body>

  <button id="pwai"><span>INSTALAR PWA</span></button>

  <script>
    let deferredPrompt;

    const installButton = document.getElementById('pwai');

    installButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (deferredPrompt) {
        deferredPrompt.prompt();
        deferredPrompt.userChoice.then(choiceResult => {
          if (choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted') {
            console.log('Usuario aceptó la instalación');
          } else {
            console.log('Usuario rechazó la instalación');
          }
          deferredPrompt = null;
        });
      }
    });
  </script>
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('serviceWorker.js', {
          updateViaCache: 'none'
        })
        .then(registration => {
          console.log('Service Worker registrado con éxito:', registration);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log('Error al registrar el Service Worker:', error);
        });
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Acá esta el **`manifest.json`**:

```
{
  "name": "Mi PWA Prueba",
  "short_name": "PWA Prueba",
  "start_url": "./pwaprueba.html",
  "display": "standalone",
  "background_color": "#ffffff",
  "theme_color": "#000000"
}
```

Comment: Todavia no pude revisar tu codigo, pero te comento. No estas en modo "privado" en el browser?  Estas con HTTPS? Pudes validar tu pagina aqui https://www.pwabuilder.com/ donde te indica que falta

Comment: quizás la ruta de tu html está mala, en serviceWorker prueba con esto `'./pwaprueba.html',`

Comment: Hola chicos! Gracias por tomarse un tiempo en revisar. Probe usando la pagina pwabuilder.com y me arrojo lo siguiente:

Edit and download your created manifest (Manifest not found before detection tests timed out)

yield result icon
Add Service Worker to Base Package (SW not found before detection tests timed out)

yield result icon
Does not use Background Sync for a rich offline experience

yield result icon
Does not use Periodic Sync for a rich offline experience

Comment: probe poniendo ./pwaprueba.html pero nada, sigue igual.

Comment: dale a "dar de baja" y ve si se te instala nuevamente